# Excel Macro selects 2 columns instead of 1

Tags: excel, vba

I need to insert 2 columns after column F

Here is the code that I have

```
Columns(6).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

For some reason, it keeps collecting column F and column G. I did check to make sure that columns F and G are not merged anywhere. When I select it manually it selects fine.

I also tried it with

```
Columns("F:F").select
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. There was one merged cell way below where the data was expected to be

Comment: This can be deleted. Really nothing useful in this question